# 物体検出のためのモデルがダウンロードできない

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow API 物体検出（Quick Start）の質問をします。
Jupyter notebookで実行していたところ、モデルのダウンロードのところで以下のエラーを吐き出してしまいました。もしこのような問題を解決する方法をご存じでしたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いいたします。
（なお、初投稿なので質問の仕方で至らない点があるかもしれません。申し訳ございません。）

エラー

```
IOError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-f921d2932261> in <module>()
      1 opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
----> 2 opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
      3 tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
      4 for file in tar_file.getmembers():
      5   file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)

/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.pyc in retrieve(self, url, filename, reporthook, data)
    242             headers = fp.info()
    243             if filename:
--> 244                 tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
    245             else:
    246                 import tempfile

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz'
```

ソースコード

```
opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
for file in tar_file.getmembers():
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
    tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
```

参考
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb

環境
Ubuntu14.04LTS
Python 2.7.6
Python 3.4.3
tensorflow 1.4.0(CPU版)
jupyter notebook 5.2.1

Comment: ファイルのダウンロード周りで失敗しているようですね。手元の生の Python では `http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17.tar.gz` を `opener.retrive` することには成功しました。Jupyter notebook ではなく生の Python の方でファイルをダウンロードすると成功しますか？

Comment: 作業しているipynbがあるディレクトリ情報もいただけませんか。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ダウンロード周りで失敗しているとのご指摘ありがとうございます。pythonでoppener.retrieveできず、原因を探っていたところ、ディレクトリが権限を持っていないことに気づきました。

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb にある ```load_model``` 関数を使ってもできませんか？「ディレクトリが権限を持っていない」というのは、あなたのローカルディレクトリなのか、それとも相手先サーバーのディレクトリなのか。後者であればURLの指定が間違っているかアクセスがブロックされた可能性があります。前者は適当にchmodとかしたらいいのでは。

Answer (score 0):

コメントで「ダウンロードは正常に実行できていますか？」と指摘をもらったことをヒントに、Python で `oppener.retrieve` できず、原因を探っていたところ、ディレクトリが権限を持っていないことに気づきました。

---

*この投稿は [@bluekye62 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40060/%e7%89%a9%e4%bd%93%e6%a4%9c%e5%87%ba%e3%81%ae%e3%81%9f%e3%82%81%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a2%e3%83%87%e3%83%ab%e3%81%8c%e3%83%80%e3%82%a6%e3%83%b3%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%83%89%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment40663_40060) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*

Answer (score 0):

2020/11/18時点では、以下の方法で実行できることを確認しています。

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

def load_model(model_name):
    base_url = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'
    model_file = model_name + '.tar.gz'
    model_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
        fname=model_name,
        origin=base_url + model_file,
        untar=True)

    model_dir = pathlib.Path(model_dir)/"saved_model"

    model = tf.saved_model.load(str(model_dir))

    return model


model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)
```

参考: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb